# Git Branches Workflow

Tags: git, branch, git-workflow

I am trying to understand branches.

Scenario: I am working on branch1 and I realized that there is another task I need to do before continuing with branch1. I don't want to delete branch1 until I am fully completed the feature. So, I want to make a branch2 and complete another task first. Once I am done with branch2, what do I do to get branch1 updated with that feature?

Do I...

- Method 1: Once completing branch2 do I merge that with the main branch and then switch to branch1 and merge it with the main branch?
- Method 2: Or do I merge branch2 and branch1, then merge that with main.

Answer (score 0):

Both methods will work if there are no conflicts between branch 2 and main.

If there are conflicts, the second method will not pick up the resolution and you will have to resolve again when merging branch 1.